# In search of Nebula Widgets javadoc

Tags: java, nebula

I am using Nebula Widgets in an RCP Eclipse app, and especially XYGRaph. I found on its GitHub page some examples([here](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula/tree/master/widgets/visualization/org.eclipse.nebula.visualization.xygraph/examples/org/eclipse/nebula/visualization/xygraph/examples)), but in order to get more information, I would like to find its javadoc, in a jar file or in an internet page.

I searched for this, but in vain: with Google, in Maven repositories, and obviously in the GitHub page.

Does it exist, and where is it? Or is there a guide?

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/visualization/visualization.php ... using google must be hard

Comment: yes, I found it also, but there isn't any XYViewer widget javadoc

Comment: you didn't ask for `XYViewer`

Comment: yes, it's an error, I mean XYGraph

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/nebula/snippets.php#Visualization

Comment: ok, thank you, but nevertheless in order to use it right it would be good to have the javadoc

Answer (score 0):

When you build an RCP application it is always wise to add the source to the target platform, this will get you the Javadoc inside Eclipse for free. Our source bundles are published in our p2 repositories (example here [5]).

We [1] have published Javadoc here [2]. We've never published it before so unfortunately, it is not error free. We will fix at least some of it for the 1.5.0 release in March 2018 [3].

Best examples are always had from the snippets. The Nebula git repo has a copy on Github here [4]

1. https://www.eclipse.org/nebula
2. https://www.eclipse.org/nebula/releases/1.4.0/javadoc/overview-summary.html
3. https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.nebula/releases/1.5.0/plan
4. https://github.com/eclipse/nebula
5. http://download.eclipse.org/nebula/releases/1.4.0/plugins/?d